# Python continue with either if or else

Tags: python, continue

In Python:
I want to continue with something2 either if something true and something3 true or else:

```
if something:
    if something3:
        number += 1
        {continue on something2}
else:
    if something2:
        if 2 == 2:
            number += 2
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Please tell us the programming language. Usually, you just do not use "else", and continue your program.

Comment: Oh, sorry, it's Python.

Comment: Then you should edit your question and specify that. Also, add the "python" tag.

Comment: Just remove the `else:`?

Comment: remove the `else` and you'll be good to go.

Comment: You just need to remove the `else`

Comment: if 'something' it has to be '1==1' to continue, if not 'something' it just continues. I don't want it to continue if '1 != 1'

Comment: remove the else and remove the continue. then chuck it all in a for loop for what ever your "something" variable is...

Comment: I want to program some huge code so I don't want to pass through everything

Answer (score 0):

The program will continue no matter what.

imagine a function like.

```
def foo(condition)
    x = 0
    if condition:
       x = x + 1
    else:
       x = x + 2

    print x
```

No matter of the condition the print will be executed. Programs don't stop just because of `if` statement.

`if` statements are simple branching. You can execute one of the branches depending on a condition. If the `if` evaluates to `true` you'll enter the first branch and execute the code after the if statement. If the condition is `false` the code after the `else` will be executed.

Edit: due to OP comment

> if something and something3 true or something false - continue

Then you should just think about your logic. You do not want to continue if `something` is `true` but `something3` is not.

```
if something:
  if something3:
     add_something()
  else:
     # do not continue. maybe return here

# continue with your code
```

Comment: But I want if something is true, something3 to be true to continue, else if something is false just continue

Comment: You want to execute a code block if `something` and `something3` are `true`?

Comment: if something and something3 true or something false - continue, but if something and something3 true i want to add something

Comment: I want to continue if something is true or false but if something is true, something3 has to be true too, and I increase a number in this case

Answer (score 0):

I think I would write it like this:

```
if something:
    if somethingElse:
        number += 1
        f()
else:
    f()
```

In two of the cases `f()` is called. It is only when `something` is true and `somethingElse` is not true does `f()` not get called.

Comment: It's lots of ifs after that, so I can't put all of them under both if and else